# How to call a Mongodb Realm function from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, realm, mongodb-atlas

I have a function deployed in Mongodb Realm that I want to call in my local nodejs app. I am able to connect to the Mongodb Atlas Cluster via the `uri` and `MongoClient`.

But they are only able to query the database and not call that function. Is there a way I can call that function using this connected instance of `MongoClient`.

I also discovered two npm packages - `realm` and `realm-web`. But I am unable to get the work done with either of them.

in `realm-web`, the docs says to use `import` like

```
import * as Realm from "realm";
```

but this doesn't work in node.

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

then in `realm`, the method to open the realm apparantly has two arguments

```
const Realm = require("realm");

const realm = Realm.open({
    path: "myrealm",
    schema: [TaskSchema],
  });
```

and I am unable to find what to fill in them.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a user object in order to call a function.

At a bare minimum, something like:

```
const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
const user = await app.logIn(credentials);
const result = await user.functions.myFunction(arg1, arg2);
```

With this, you'll need to enable anonymous authentication (or a different auth provider for something more secure) and ensure that the function isn't private.

Referencing the docs:

Getting a user object: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/examples/authenticate-users/

Calling a function: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/examples/call-a-function/